# How do I add a class to local task links in Twig template?

Tags: theming, 8

I've used custom templates to add BEM style classes to both the local tasks UL wrapper and the individual LI items, I'd like to also add a class to the actual local task (tab) link.

This is the default code in the Classy template:

```
<li{{ attributes.addClass(is_active ? 'is-active') }}>{{ link }}</li>
```

Is there no way to simply add a class to the `{{ link }}` item?

Answer (score 13):

```
{% set link = link|merge({ '#attributes': { 'class': [ 'your', 'custom', 'classes' ] } }) %}

<li>{{ link }}</li>
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Try to explain what the code does and why it solves OP's problem.

Comment: It's the solution and self explanatory. Clean and clear way.

Answer (score 4):

you can add a class with the attribute array of the TWIG function :

```
{{ link(item.title, item.url, { 'class':['my-custom-class'] }) }}
```

unfortunately, this overrides any classes added preprocessing by other contrib modules.  Im currently looking for a way to append new class to the {{ link }}

Answer (score 2):

You can't from the template, but you can do it from a preprocess hook. If you look at the original from Drupal:

```
function template_preprocess_menu_local_task(&$variables) {
  ...
  $variables['link'] = array(
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#title' => $link_text,
    '#url' => $link['url'],
    '#options' => $link['localized_options'],
  );
}
```

In a theme, you could add a class in your own preprocess, something like this should do the trick:

```
function THEME_preprocess_menu_local_task(&$variables) {
  $variables['link']['#options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'my-extra-class';
}
```